# Naming convention in association between objects of the same class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an application with the typical social features: essentially, two users can be friends. This is done through an associative class called "Friendship" that contains the id of the two users. Obviously both keys can't be called "user_id". The normal way would be to give different names to both keys and make it work with :class_name.

The problem is that the relation is completely reciprocal, as the friendship can't be only one-side: it works like Facebook, not like Twitter. I don't want to add information naming the keys "creator" and "acceptor", and using numbers "user_1_id" or "user_2_id" sounds terrible.

The question: is there any convention in Rails for this naming problem?

Comment: there are only two hard things in computer science... http://laughingmeme.org/2005/12/23/there-are-only-two-hard-things-in-computer-science-cache-invalidation-and-naming-things/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically normalize the data in such situations.

```
class User
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends
end

class Friendship
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"

  after_create :reciprocate_friendship

  def reciprocate_friendship    
    return if friend.friends.exists?(user) # do nothing if reciprocal friendship exists
    friend.friends << user
  end
end
```

This way you are optimizing the friend queries.

**Edit**

If you must store the friend relationship in one row then add an additional association to the `User` model:

```
has_many :network_friends, :class_name => "User", :finder_sql => Proc.new {
  %Q{
    SELECT * FROM users
    JOIN friendships 
      ON (users.id = friendships.user_id OR users.id = friendships.friend_id)
    WHERE users.id = #{id}
  }
}
```

Now you can use the new association as follows:

```
user1.friends  << user2
user3.friends << user1
user1.network_friends # [ user2, user3]
```

Comment: But like this you are duplicating data. A friendship between user 1 and 2 would generate two records in the FriendShip table.

Comment: You are normalizing the data so that your friend queries are significantly faster. You will have to resort to using lot of custom sql to get the standard rails association. Data duplication is a small cost to pay compared to the convenience of accessing the data expediently. I have updated my answer with a solution to store friend ship in one row.

Comment: Does no one else here find it funny that **friendship** is supposed to be a single word?

Comment: @Pierre, it is funny. It is a case of over using camel casing. Thanks for the comment, I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [railscasts tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) on this subject using `user` and `friend` which seems sensible. It also has support for the reciprocal relation.

Comment: Yes, but I don't like that solution. We talk about friends, not about friends and "inverse_friends". Maybe that would be more or less OK, if it included a third relation that is the result of joining the other two.